# converting values in multiple columns in a dataframe to integer

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
V1  V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10   V11
8   10   0.2  0.4   0   0.0  1.2  0.2  4.2  3.4   2.5
4   5    1.0   0    2   4.5   0   1.1   0    1    2.0
.....................................
```

i.e., columns from V2-V11 has some decimal values. What I wish to do is that all of them in multiple rows (2000) are converted to integers.

I tried using the

```
apply(df, 1, as.integer())
```

But, it doesn't work.

Comment: Saying "*it doesn't worked*" is rarely helpful. The error message would have been informative in this case (rather than people assume you got an undesired result). *`'as.integer()' is not a function, character or symbol`*. You meant `apply( df , 1 , as.integer )`. The `()` are used at the command line so the parser realises it is calling a function. It is not needed to match a function to a name given as an argument to another function.

Answer (score 0):

From he R documentation for `as.integer`:

> Non-integral numeric values are truncated towards zero (i.e., as.integer(x) equals trunc(x) there), and imaginary parts of complex numbers are discarded (with a warning).

So it sounds like we can use just `trunc` here.

```
> trunc(df)
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
# 1  8 10  0  0  0  0  1  0  4   3   2
# 2  4  5  1  0  2  4  0  1  0   1   2
```

Comment: However, if I see the dimensions, my dataframe had 7357 rows across 27 columns. However, after I apply this, the result is a large matrix with 198639 elements. Why is that?

Comment: After you call `floor()`?  Or `sapply()`?  I removed `sapply()`

Comment: I used sapply and apply both. Both leads to this matrix.

Comment: It works perfectly with floor. However, no, with apply and sapply it leads to the formation of a matrix with different dimensions, having 198639 elements

Comment: Don't use `apply` it'll coerce to a matrix which you'll have to convert back again. `floor` must have a method for `data.frame`s as it keeps the structure intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a class

```
setClass("NumerictoInteger")
setAs("character", "NumerictoInteger", function(from) as.integer(from))
dat <- read.table(text="V1  V2   V3   V4   V5   V6   V7   V8   V9   V10   V11
8   10   0.2  0.4   0   0.0  1.2  0.2  4.2  3.4   2.5
4   5    1.0   0    2   4.5   0   1.1   0    1      2.0",sep="",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,colClasses="NumerictoInteger")

dat
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11
1  8 10  0  0  0  0  1  0  4   3   2
2  4  5  1  0  2  4  0  1  0   1   2
```